# unbind submit event in AJAX callback

Tags: jquery, callback, unbind

If a checkbox is not checked, I alert and prevent form submission (either submit button click or Enter) with bind false.  I need to unbind in the AJAX callback, but am unable to do so.

HTML:

```
<form action="act.php" onsubmit="formSubmit()" id="TypeForm" name="TypeForm" method="POST">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="1">
<span>Type 1</span>
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="2">
<span>Type 2</span>
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
<script>
  function formSubmit() {
    var self=this;
    $(self).bind('submit', false);
    if ($('#TypeForm').find('input:radio:checked').length == 0) {
      alert('A selection is required.');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "add.php",
          success: function() {
            $(self).unbind();
          }
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot event name - `$(self).unbind('submit');` ?

Comment: I left the sample code in the most generic form possible, to unbind all events bound by JQuery.  I had previously tried unbinding the specific event (.submit) and had also created a separate handler and tried unbinding just that handler - none would unbind and allow the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to stop the normal submission of a form when user hits Enter or clicks the submit button? Then you need to prevent the `event` from taking the default action. Try this:

```
function formSubmit(event) {
    var self=this;

    event.preventDefault();

    if ($('#TypeForm').find('input:radio:checked').length == 0) {
      alert('A selection is required.');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "add.php",
          success: function() {
            $(self).unbind();
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

---

**Edit:** And as Trevor mentions, you should use jQuery to bind your function so that the `event` is properly setup to work across different browsers. The code could be:

```
$(function() {
  $('#TypeForm').submit(formSubmit);
});
```

But I would rewrite your code like this (NOT tested):

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    $('#TypeForm').submit(function (event) {
      var self=this;

      event.preventDefault();

      if ($(this).find('input:radio:checked').length === 0) {
        alert('A selection is required.');
        return false;
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        success: function (data) {
          alert('success, data: ' + data); // optional
          // no need for this: $(self).unbind();
        }
      });
    }
  });

</script>
```

And remove the `onsubmit="formSubmit()"` from your HTML.

Comment: I am only trying to prevent the form submit when no radio button has been clicked.  If one is clicked, I want the AJAX call performed (add a DB record) and submit the form which continues on to the next page.  I rewrote the code as per the example you provided (except there is a missing ); on the last } but the preventDefault keeps the form from being submitted and advancing to act.php.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
    var self=this;

Should be

```
var self=$(this)
```

Secondly,
 You must bind the form to the submit action within the event model of jQuery in order to access $(this).

Example:

```
$(function() { // short hand document ready call
   $('form-name').submit(function(formSubmit());
}
```

Also, why do you want to unbind it?

Comment: Is there a difference?, it is the same thing (I'm referring to changing self=this to self=$(this))

Comment: No, but for readability purposes it is helpful. Not to mention the fact that it's much easier to handle the objects properties and methods if you need to use it multiple times over the course of a function. Typically, people will assign $(this) to a variable called $this.

Comment: Fair enough, it's just that your answer sounds like that change is mandatory for things to work.

Comment: @Trevor - thank you, I had the self=$(this) syntax at some point (I've tried many iterations over several hours), but didn't bring it in the code paste - sorry - thanks for the tip. As to binding the form to the submit action - I couldn't quite get the syntax correct when trying the example provided.  The purpose in unbinding was to go ahead and submit the form after the completion of the AJAX call - (to continue on to act.php).

Comment: Sure. Try using Firebug to see if the function is running properly and find out if $(this) is retrieving the object properly. console.log($(this)); within the formSubmit function. Good luck.